# Kafka consumer not able to read new msg?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am relatively new to Kafka, I am trying to spawn consumer after messages are sent on topic.

the single producer sends 200 msg on different a partition.

consumer-1 was already running,  consumer-1 is listening to all 4 partitions and within a few seconds, another consumer is started (consumer-2) in the same group. Then Kafka trigger rebalances of the group, but all the initial 200  msg will go to the consumer-1 and new msg will come to consumer-2.
after the new consumer is created, describe consumer-group API show
`Warning: Consumer group 'ner_group' is rebalancing.`

Can anyone suggest how to add new consumer in the consumer-group, to read msg which are already sent to a topic, while another consumer is already reading from that topic?

Below contains the config of consumer and producer.

producer

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=[f'{ip}:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: 
                         dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
for e in range(200):
    data = {'count':e ,'time':time.time() }
    producer.send('ner', value=data)
```

consumer

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'ner',
    bootstrap_servers=[f'{ip}:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='ner_group',
    value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
    )

for message in consumer:
    msg = message.value
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am running consumer scripts multiple times.

Comment: You'll want producer.flush() after your loop

Answer (score 0):

> all the initial 200 msg will go to the consumer-1 and new msg will come to consumer-2

That may be what you're experiencing, but that's not the guaranteed behavior.

> how to add new consumer in the consumer-group, to read msg which are already sent to a topic, while another consumer is already reading from that topic?

What you're doing is correct. Adding another consumer won't read from offsets in the group that have already been committed